# Class atributes get linked when using tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, spyder

I'm using a tkinter interface to read in some information like file path, measurement variables etc. for my code. And I read them out with the use_entry function which just remains here as a kill command for the app.  Then I run the code a few times to analyze different data sets.

It seems to work fine but i noticed that if two attributes get the same value (here exp and pwr) they get scrambled. Meaning that both become the same value permanently. So if i set exp to A and pwr to B i can freely change them , but as soon as I set both to the same string or int or whatever they start being changed simultaneously (here both are "A"). I can't resolve this unless i restart the consol or change one of the values outside of tkinter.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.exp="A"
        self.pwr="A"
        self.parent=parent

        self.exposure = tk.Entry(parent, textvariable=self.exp)
        self.exposure.pack()

        self.power = tk.Entry(parent, textvariable=self.pwr)
        self.power.pack()


        self.button4 = tk.Button(parent, 
                           text="Done", 
                           command=self.use_entry)

        self.button4.pack()



    def use_entry(self):
        self.contents = (float(self.power.get()),float(self.exposure.get()))
        self.parent.destroy()


root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I'm rather new to using tkinter and I would be glad if someone could point out my mistake.

Comment: Read, what is [textvariable=](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Use [tk.StringVar](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) instead of normal strings for textvariable in your entries.

```
self.exp = tk.StringVar(value='A')
self.pwr = tk.StringVar(value='A')
self.parent=parent

self.exposure = tk.Entry(parent, textvariable=self.exp)
self.exposure.pack(side=tk.LEFT,anchor=tk.W)

self.power = tk.Entry(parent, textvariable=self.pwr)
self.power.pack()
```

Comment: Thank you this works, but it is actually possible to reproduce my error with tkinter variables you just have to try xD. When using the .get() instead of the normal variable. Why does tkinter mess up normal variables like this? Do Tkinter variables have a label which tkinter takes values of normal variables for?